# How to store a variable of an instance of a class in an instance of another class

Tags: python, class, gurobi

I have two self-defined classes, one is a child of the gurobipy-class and is supposed to make a lp-model. The other one I made to store variables. Now I want to store some variables of the model class in the variables class.
Here are my classes:

```
class Model(gb.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def create_model(self, var):
        dim = var.dimensions()
        # variables
        x = self.addVars(dim[0], dim[1], vtype=gb.GRB.BINARY, name="x")
        D_l = self.addVars(dim[1], lb=0, name='D_l')
        D_max = self.addVar(lb=0, name='D_max')
        # objective
        self.setObjective(D_max, gb.GRB.MINIMIZE)
        # constraints
        self.addConstrs((x.sum(i, '*') == 1 for i in range(dim[0])), name="b")
        self.addConstrs((D_max >= D_l[l] for l in range(dim[1])), name="c")
        self.addConstrs((D_l[l] >= var.dist_mat()[i, j] * (x[i, l] + x[j, l] - 1) for i in range(dim[0])
                          for j in range(dim[0]) for l in range(dim[1])), name='a')
        self.update()


class Variables:
    def __init__(self, data, number_of_clusters, neighbourhood_size):
        self.data = data
        self.number_of_clusters = number_of_clusters
        self.neighbourhood_size = neighbourhood_size
        self.variables_before = None
        self.variables_now = None
        self.ofv_before = None
        self.ofv_now = None
        self.x = None

    def dist_mat(self):
        from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
        return distance_matrix(self.data, self.data)

    def dimensions(self):
        from numpy import shape
        data_objects = shape(self.data)[0]
        number_of_clusters = self.number_of_clusters
        return data_objects, number_of_clusters

    def print_dist_mat(self):
        print(self.dist_mat())
```

It's the x-variable I want to store. First, I tried to store it in the instance of the Model-class. I added to the **init**-function this line `self.x = None`. But it raise an `AttributeError: 'x' is not a model attribute`. I guess, this is because the gurobipy-class doesn't have a x attribute.

Next, I wanted to store it in an instance of the variable-class. I wanted to write a function in the model class, which should do the trick. This is the function:

```
def store_x(self, var):
    var.x = self.x
```

Then, I got this error: `gurobipy.GurobiError: Unable to retrieve attribute 'x'`, I can't understand why.

I can't even access the x-variable from outside the function. I can print it from inside the function, but nothing more. The problem is, I need this x-variable in a later stage.

How can I achieve this? How can I store the x-variable to access it at a later point? It doesn't have to be in the variable-class, any other solution is appreciated as well.

Comment: Did you solve the model yet?

Comment: Yes, it works just fine and finishes with exit-code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first off I see an issue with Your code:

```
def store_x(self, var):
    var.x = self.x
```

It Needs to be changed to :

```
def store_x(self, var):
    self.x = var.x
```

This is because whatever you send in the 'var' parameter will only be a copy of whatever you actually passed.  And then its scope will only last to the end of that store_x method.  So instead you pass that copy and tell your variable class instance to store it inside it's x value.

As for the error you got with:

```
self.x = None # inside your Model class
```

I'm not sure why, as I tried the following and it runs fine:

```
class Variables:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data
        self.number_of_clusters = number_of_clusters
        self.neighbourhood_size = neighbourhood_size
        self.variables_before = None
        self.variables_now = None
        self.ofv_before = None
        self.ofv_now = None
        self.x = None
```

So I'm updating my answer with a deeper example after getting clarification on what is needed.  Here are two skeleton classes named 'Variables', 'Model', respectivly:

```
class Variables:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.number_of_clusters = None
        self.neighbourhood_size = None
        self.variables_before = None
        self.variables_now = None
        self.ofv_before = None
        self.ofv_now = None
        self.x = None


    def get_x(self,modelx):

        self.x = modelx


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = ({}, {})



# create your class instances here

newVar = Variables()
newModel = Model()

# one way to assign your Variable class's x attribute the tuple dict in question.  
newVar.x = newModel.x 

# alternate way is to create a function inside your Variable class that updates the x variable based on the argument you send it.  
newVar.get_x(newModel.x)
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. I think, I wasn't specific: the statement self.x = None was in the init-method of the Model-class, not the Variable-class and so was the store_x-method. Because the x-variable is a tupledict and defined during the setup of the model and I want this tupledict stored in the Variable-class. In this case, in which class should I write the store_x-method?

Comment: ok so what you're trying to do is send the actual value inside the Model's x variable over to the Var-Class.  Just send it inside the argument, instead of trying to access it's x attribute from within the method.  Let me update my answer with an example